# Phonegap WEB-APP without xCode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, web-applications, cordova

I'm building a simple web app for iOS that will not be published to the AppStore.
For infrastructure limits (and my boss!) , I can't use xCode anyway to build the app in a native way.

The only NATIVE functionality required by the web app should be a simple "Add to contacts".

I've tried to implement it with phonegap , but it works only compiled under xCode.

Is there any way to "add to contacts" without building an app (using only a web-app )?

Thanks in advance
Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a way for you to add a contact directly, using only a web app.

PhoneGap was made for this sort of thing, allowing you to access a device's features (like Contacts, Camera, GPS, etc). But if your company's project specifications don't allow for an app... I don't know that there's a way to do this directly, via the web.

If you're building a web app... while you may be targeting iPhones, you're still making it available to anyone with a browser. I'm not 100% on this, but having some way for a web page to directly manipulate a (Mac) user's contacts seems like a security issue.

As a test, I tried placing a [vCard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard) on a page, and accessing it via my iPhone. Changing the extension from .vcf to .vcard didn't yield anything (and for some weird reason it prompted me to open the file via Dropbox).

What did work was emailing myself the vcard as an attachment. I was able to view the attachment, which then gave me the option to add the info as a new contact.